# Send Mail from HANA SQL trigger

Tags: sql, hana

I am working on a HANA SQL trigger and got a requirement to send a notification email if a condition is matched.

So please guide me how to proceed on this.

Comment: You can populate a queue table from trigger and process this table with a job in ABAP side to send emails

Comment: I am not using ABAP backend, so I can't follow this approach

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible (until now) to trigger an email notification within a HANA trigger.